# Versioning approach - Numbers vs Adjectives

Tags: design-patterns, naming-conventions, naming

Mostly this question has no certain answer, but I wonder the opinion of the community. We're going to implement a new version of data models (we're going to support existing one for a while). And currently, we have a few options to implement naming:

1) Use some implementation sign (like `User` -> `gmUser`). I don't like it first because it doesn't give us a solution for future changes. Plus I don't want to link interface name to an implementation

2) Use numbers for versioning (like `User` -> `v2User` / `User2` , `User3` and so on) - this is more widely spread approach. But such naming looks strange for me. Plus there is a sub-proposal to rename `User3` -> `User` as soon as no one uses original `User`

3) Use prefixes for versions (like `User` -> `AwesomeUser`, `Application` -> `AwesomeApplication`). Under the hood, it supposed to follow an alphabetic order, but in general, such naming just says that `User` and `AwesomeUser` are different entities.

I'm personally for the 3rd option. But my counterparts say that no one uses that option. And there is a reason for it. I know that those who use such naming mostly do it for marketing. But for me, it makes the code more readable.

I wonder about community opinions and some profs for best practices.

Thanks in advance

P.S. to give more context - it's about GraphQL Queries mostly, so `User1` / `User2` - difference currently not in the list of fields, while in structure about abilities

Comment: The best options from the worst ones is `User, User2, User3` in my opinion. But Better just extend your model and mark old stuff as outdated (deprecated). Versioning is evil.

Comment: @DmitryPavlov what do you mean by extending?

Answer (score 0):

what about to implement versioning on file structure level

```
/models
  /ver1
    /User.js
  /ver2
    /User.js
```

it allows just to change import path but save naming in code

Answer (score 0):

We used second approach (`User`, `User2`).

1. It's clear that naming is temporary and finally only one survives (Of course if you are not going to support both models) while `User` and `AwesomeUser` may look like you need both versions of the model for different reasons
2. Alphabetic order. We wanted `User` and `User2` to be in the same place.

You also can rename all current models now to `*Legacy` and just create `User` as a new version. This way you just need to remove all `*Legacy` after refactoring

Comment: By renaming current ones to `*Legacy`, you are forcing everyone, who's not ready yet to switch to new version, to switch to `legacy` version.

Comment: And then when they will be ready, they will have to do one more switching to new version.

Comment: @KarlenKishmiryan It is a problem only if you create a third-party module. But in case of a project it is easy to just rename all entries.